# No symbols in Go plugin

Tags: go

I am trying to use Go's plugin system. Even with a very basic example, I'm unable to find any symbols in a compiled plugin. My setup looks like this:

```
/Users/blah/test-workspace/
  src/
    main/
      main.go
    plug/
      plug.go
```

`plug.go` looks like this:

```
package main

type B struct {}

func main() {}
```

From the `/Users/blah/test-workspace/` directory, I build this using:

```
GOPATH="/Users/blah/test-workspace" go build -buildmode plugin plug
```

This produces `p.so` inside the root of the GOPATH. Next I try to load this plugin via `main/main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "plugin"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    plugin, err := plugin.Open("plug.so")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %+v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", plugin)
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
&{pluginpath:plug err: loaded:0xc420088060 syms:map[]}
```

As you can, the symbol map is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JimB That's the answer, post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [plugin docs](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/)

> A symbol is any exported variable or function

You need to add an exported variable or function in order for your plugin to work.